# How to allow users to assign a instances or something that can work the same way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

What I am trying to do is to make an app so, while the user is using the app he can add an instance for a class.
To be more specific, I am trying to make a rating app for the workers but, I need to make the user to be able to add a worker to the app which I want to be treated as an instance in the backend code which has a class called **worker**.
and here is the code to understand what I am trying to say more.

```
class worker:
    """
    This class is responsible for any worker been rated.
    INPUT:  name of rated worker
    OUTPUT: the rating
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def rate(self):

        rating = input(f"What is your rating for {self.name}")

        #open a file and append the rating to it.
        rat_stor = open(f"{self.name}rating_storage", "a+")
        rat_stor.write(rating + ",")
        rat_stor.close()

        #open a file and read it.
        rat_stor = open(f"{self.name}rating_storage", "r")
        rat_stor_read = rat_stor.read()
        rat_stor.close()

        #I have the all the ratings as a list.
        lis_rat = rat_stor_read.split(",")

        #going to be used as a filter for non-numerical values
        int_lis = []

        for i in lis_rat:
            #if the string can be converted to an integer then, add it to int_lis
            try:
                int_lis.append(int(i))
            except:
                pass


        rates_sum = sum(int_lis)
        rates_amount = len(int_lis)
        self.result = rates_sum / rates_amount

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + str(round(self.result,1))
```

Comment: There are no problems with the indenting I suppose!

Comment: Ah someone edited it. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do - if you need instance then create it `instance = worker()`. BTW; it is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - ie. `class Worker`.

Comment: maybe you should create `class Application` and inside this class ask for names and create instances of `Worker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design a user interface for your program - if you want a windowed application then you could either use [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tkinter.html) (built in to python) or you could find a package that does the job you want (installable using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/)). Or you could make a web app with a package such as [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). If this isn't a commercial application then the simplest option is to just make a command line application (using `print` and `input`)

For a windowed/graphical application: you need to consider what process the user should go through to add a worker/submit a rating. Presumably some data needs to be inputted (their name, etc.) The package you choose will allow you to build an interface for this.

**Edit:**

A command line app that illustrates how you might make a menu system, Allows you to create/rate workers. Error handling is very limited and workers are not saved to disk so they will be lost when the program is closed. I recommend looking into a module called `pickle` for saving data to disk - much more powerful that manually writing to a file. **This example is written for Python version >3. For Python 2 you will need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input`**

```
# --- file name: manageworkers.py ---
class Worker: #I'm using this in place of your class for simplicity
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.ratings = []

    def rate(self):
        #Normally code that takes user input should be with the rest of the code for the menu. Have put this here to stay consistent with your code.
        print("What is your rating for {}?".format(self.name))
        self.ratings.append(input(">"))
        print("Rating saved!")

workers = []

def mainMenu():
    while True:
        print("Please select an option:")
        print("\t1) Add a worker")
        print("\t2) Rate a worker")
        print("\t3) View worker ratings")
        print("\t4) Exit")
        while True:
            choice = int(input(">")) #Will break if you don't enter a valid number
            if choice == 1:
               addWorker()
               break
            elif choice == 2:
               rateWorker()
               break
            elif choice == 3:
                viewRatings()
                break
            elif choice == 4:
                return
            else:
                print("Invalid selection - please try again")

def addWorker():
    global workers
    newWorker = Worker() #This is where the instance is created
    print("What is the name of the worker?")
    newWorker.name = input(">")
    workers.append(newWorker) #Keep the worker somewhere so we can use it later
    print("Worker Saved!")

def chooseWorker():
    global workers
    if len(workers) == 0:
        print("There are no workers.")
        return
    #Let's print a menu
    print("Please select a worker:")
    for n, w in enumerate(workers):
        print("\t{}) {}".format(n+1, w.name)) #Add one to n so numbering starts at 1

    #Now we need to work out what the user entered
    while True:
        selection = int(input(">")) - 1 #Take the one away again so array indexing starts at 0. Will break if you don't enter a number.
        if selection >= 0 and selection < len(workers):
            return workers[selection]
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid selection, please try again.") 

def rateWorker():
    workerToRate = chooseWorker()
    if workerToRate != None:
        workerToRate.rate()

def viewRatings():
    workerToView = chooseWorker()
    if workerToView != None:
        if len(workerToView.ratings) == 0:
            print("Worker has no ratings.")
        else:
            print("Ratings for {}:".format(workerToView.name))
            for rating in workerToView.ratings:
                print("\t{}".format(rating))

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: I want it to be a command-line app, and I would ask the user if he wants to add a worker etc.. and he enters a name. Then I want to use this name as an instance for the class (worker).